# Не выполняется код PHP

Tags: php

Вообщем есть что-то типа [движка](http://blog.ox2.ru/php/php-prostoy-dvizhok/).

```
class Engine {

    private $_page_file = null;
    private $_error = null;

    public function __construct() {
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { //Если открыта какая-нибудь страница
            //Записываем в переменную имя открытого файла (из GET запроса)
            $this->_page_file = $_GET["page"]; 
            //Небольшая защита
            $this->_page_file = str_replace(".", null, $_GET["page"]);
            $this->_page_file = str_replace("/", null, $_GET["page"]);
            $this->_page_file = str_replace("", null, $_GET["page"]);

             //Проверяем, если шаблон не существует
            if (!file_exists("templates/" . $this->_page_file . ".php")) {
                $this->_setError("Шаблон не найден"); //Ошибку на экран
                $this->_page_file = "main"; //Открываем главную страницу
            }
        }
         //Если в GET запросе нет переменной page, то открываем главную
        else $this->_page_file = "main";
    }

    /**
     * Записывает ошибку в переменную _error
     * @param string $error - текст ошибки
     * @author ox2.ru 
     */
    private function _setError($error) {
        $this->_error = $error;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает текст ошибки
     * @author ox2.ru 
     */
    public function getError() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает текст открытой страницы
     */
    public function getContentPage() {
        return file_get_contents("templates/" . $this->_page_file . ".php");
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает тег заголовок открытой страницы
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        switch ($this->_page_file) {
            case "main":
                return "Главная страница сайта ox2.ru";
                break;
            case "about":
                return "О компании ox2.ru";
                break;
            case "ox2":
                return "Преимущества ox2.ru";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Как в этом месте

```
 /**
 * Возвращает текст открытой страницы
 */
public function getContentPage() {
    return file_get_contents("templates/" . $this->_page_file . ".php");
}
```

вставить на страницу без `file_get_contents`, а типа include?

Comment: А чем include не устроил ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, если в подключаемом файле идет прямой вывод данных, include стоит обернуть в [буфер](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
include "templates/" . $this->_page_file . ".php";
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

В таком случае, все переменные текущей области видимости [будут доступны](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) в подключаемом файле (что может быть как полезно, так и нежелательно).

Так же, в подключаемом файле можно использовать код, возвращающий какие-либо данные. Например, такое использование так же допустимо:

```
// template.php
<?php 
return "Hello, $data!";

// engine
$data = 'World';
$result = include 'template.php'; // $result = 'Hello, World!'
```